# Auto-reproducir vídeo con sonido

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, video

Estoy trabajando con un un proyecto web en el cual se visualizan vídeos. El problema aquí es que para poder auto-reproducir un vídeo tengo que silenciar el sonido y lo que necesito es que el vídeo se auto-reproduzca sin asilenciar el sonido, no se si haya alguna forma de solucionarlo usando javascript o jquery
o existe alguna otra forma.

Por el momento solo tengo esto:

```
<video id="videoClase" style="width: 400px;" autoplay muted controls poster="portada.jpg">
   <source src="5afdc1c5532a3.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
   Tu navegador no soporta HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: Cuando dices que la autorreproducción te obliga a silenciar el audio del video, significa que ya probaste sin el atributo `muted`?

Comment: @Alfabravo asi es y cuando quito el atributo muted no se autoreproduce

Answer (score 1):

Solo quita el muted de tu html

```
<video id="videoClase" style="width: 400px;" autoplay controls poster="portada.jpg">
  <source src="5afdc1c5532a3.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  Tu navegador no soporta HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: No autoreproduce el vídeo

Answer (score 1):

Todo indica que depende del navegador en el que intentes reproducir el video.

Siguiendo a otras personas que han preguntado [lo mismo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075941/html5-video-how-to-enable-non-muted-autoplay-in-chrome-for-android), en Chrome parece haber (o había) un parámetro que controlaba esta opción: `Gesture requirement for media playback` / `Autoplay policy` en `chrome://flags`.

En Abril de 2018 ajustaron el Autoplay policy y en la [web de devs de Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) están los criterios para que puedas hacer autoplay con audio.

```
Muted autoplay is always allowed.
Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
    User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
    On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound.
    The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on desktop.
Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.
```

En Mozilla, parece tratarse de Progressive Web Apps [enlace](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/progressive-web-apps-firefox-android/)